# Convert array of array into array of hash - Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to be able to turn this array of array:

```
[["Cargo Freight", 37],
 ["Semiconductor", 35]]
```

Into this array of hash:

```
[
  {
    name: "Cargo Freight", 
    id: 37
   },
   {
    name: "Semiconductor", 
    id: 35
   }]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning how you got this anonymous array of data in the first place... There's a good chance you *lost* the `id` and `name` information unnecessarily, and are now trying to patch it back in again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```rb
array = [["Cargo Freight", 37],["Semiconductor", 35]]
array.map { |a| { name: a[0], id: a[1] } }
```

Comment: Using *array decomposition* would arguably improve readability:`array.map { |name, id| { name: name, id: id } }`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with the ruby `reduce` method

```
a = [["Cargo Freight", 37], ["Semiconductor", 35]]
a.reduce([]) { |array, el| array << {name: el.first, id: el.last}  }
```

OR

```
a.reduce([]) { |array, el| array << [[:name, :id], el].to_h}
```

Comment: Over-engineered.

Comment: `map` can _definitely_ be implemented in terms of `reduce`, but doing so outside of an academic exercise is definitely reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I agree with the other two commenters. We all know that `reduce` is universal, in other words that *every loop can be implemented with `reduce`*. That doesn't mean that it's a good idea to do so, if there is a more specialized iterator available. Heck, if you search the [tag:ruby] tag on [so], you will find an answer of mine, where I implemented *the entirety of `Enumerable`* only using `reduce` (instead of `each`), so clearly it can be done, and it is actually quite easy and also fun. But *should* it be done? Definitely no.

Comment: What you have here is just an obfuscated version of `map` that is harder to read because you first have to mentally simulate the code in your head until you realized that it's just `map`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
KEYS = %i[name id]

array = [["Cargo Freight", 37],["Semiconductor", 35]]
array.map { |e| KEYS.zip(e).to_h }
#=> [{:name=>"Cargo Freight", :id=>37}, {:name=>"Semiconductor", :id=>35}]
```